# get instagram public media using new api

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get the 10 latest instagram photos of a public profile in my nodejs app:

```
const request = require('request');

const accessToken = '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890';

const url = `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1470414259/media/recent/?access_token=${accessToken}&count=10`;

request.get(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {

console.log('print the body: ', body);
});
```

my attempt is not successful, and i get no results. 
Could somebody help me get this going?

i am trying to follow the example here : https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

### update:

i updated the username to user ID, but i am still getting no response:

```
{ meta: 
   { code: 400,
     error_type: 'APINotFoundError',
     error_message: 'this user does not exist' } }
```

### update 2:

actually i realize that my access token has some restrictions:

```
{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."}}
```

why is this happening? i am just trying to get some public profile feeds.

### update 3:

is there any other way to bypass these access token permissions and just get the 10 media of a public user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the json that this link is returning: 
`https://www.instagram.com/aa/?__a=1`

```
  body.user.media[0] will give you the last photo object
  body.user.media[1] will give you the photo before the last one object
```

.. and so on.

what you have to do here is change `aa` in the url I provided to your desired username.

ps. you might use some json viewer tools to organize the json if you browser doesn't support that

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems there:

First of all the endpoint receives the user ID as param (not the username):

```
const url = `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/${userId}/media/recent/?access_token=${accessToken}&count=10`;
```

Besides that, the endpoint responds with an object that has only one element: `data`, that is an array. So I don't know what data you are trying to get but you won't get it in `body.user`, you should go through the array and ask for the user in the corresponding position, for example try this: `console.log(body.data[0].user)`.

And you of course must define a valid access token!

Comment: i am trying to get the last 10 photos of this public profile. where should i look for the URLs of these photos?

Comment: my access token is valid, i updated the user ID to the actuall user ID of the public profile. Now, i get: `{ meta: 
   { code: 400,
     error_type: 'APINotFoundError',
     error_message: 'this user does not exist' } }` ...  could you please help?

Comment: Your problem may be that your app has not been reviewed by Instagram yet. Check out this link: https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/